# MapView annotations change their layer order when touched

Tags: iphone, xcode

Small question, i've got a few annotations on a map view. Sometimes they tend to overlap when they are very close to each other and that's ok, but when i touch them they switch their layer position. Those that were in the back are now in the front and vice versa.

So i checked my didSelectAnnotation function but there is literarily no code in that function so it couldn't be it.

I couldn't think of anything else that might cause it.

Do you know how to fix it so it won't change layer position??

This is my viewForAnnotation code:

```
annImg = [[szAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];


        szPointAnnotation *pointAnnotation = annotation;
        if (appDelegate.homePage || ([pointAnnotation.tag intValue] >= 10000))
        {
            annImg.canShowCallout = NO;
            annImg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            annImg.frame = CGRectMake(0, /*0*/-78, 70, /*78*/156);



            UIImageView *currentUserPictureView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 60)];

            int newTag = [pointAnnotation.tag intValue]-10000;
            UIImage *currentUserPicture;
            if ([pointAnnotation.tag intValue] >= 10000) {
                currentUserPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:[usersData getKeyForIndexWithKey:@"UserImageData" forIndex:newTag]];
            }else{
                currentUserPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:[usersData getKeyForIndexWithKey:@"UserImageData" forIndex:[pointAnnotation.tag intValue]]];
            }


            currentUserPictureView.image = currentUserPicture;
            userLocationButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 78)];
            [userLocationButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [userLocationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(centerOnUser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            if ([pointAnnotation.tag intValue] >= 10000) {
                userLocationButton.tag = newTag;
            }else{
                userLocationButton.tag = [pointAnnotation.tag intValue];
            }


            [userLocationButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [annImg addSubview:userLocationButton];
            [userLocationButton addSubview:currentUserPictureView];


            [userLocationButton release];
            [currentUserPictureView release];
            [currentUserPicture release];
        }
```

Comment: just remove drag delegate

Comment: how many delegate are you using?

Comment: <MKMapViewDelegate,MKAnnotation,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,BSForwardGeocoderDelegate>

Comment: delegate method...like  didSelectAnnotation???

Comment: oh.. i'm using didSelectAnnotation, viewForAnnotation, viewForOverlay, regionDidChange, regionWillChange… but non of these are activated on annotation touch except for didSelectAnnotation which has no meaningful code in it

Comment: put your didSelectAnnotation, viewForAnnotation, code

Comment: i added my viewForAnnotation code. I tried to delete the didSelectAnnotation function and it still happened so it couldn't be it.

Comment: have you tried to do maximum zoom?

Comment: and what's the problem if front is back and back is frnt... it will display current selected in front

Comment: I want it to select only the one in the front

Comment: when you select any annotation then it will display in front..and other in back..